# PHP Array key does not match itself

Tags: php, arrays

I have a quite complex PHP application, but XDebug helped to track the problem down to a point, where I don't understand PHP anymore. I try to elaborate on the hopefully relevant core of the issue.

There is a class hierarchy ModelCore->Model->LMC->MC. In LMC there is an insert() method, which has the following line of code:

```
if($this->createEntry($mKey)) return $this->getEntry($mKey);
```

The `getEntry` method is also defined in LMC:

```
function getEntry($mKey){
   if(array_key_exists($mKey, $this->aItemList) || $this->createEntry($mKey)) return $this->aItemList[$mKey];
   return false;
}
```

`createEntry` is abstract in LMC and defined in MC:

```
function createEntry($mKey){
   if(array_key_exists($mKey, $this->aItemList) && ($this->aItemList[$mKey] instanceof LCI))
      return false;
   $this->aItemList[$mKey] = new $this->sItemClass($this,$mKey,(!array_key_exists($mKey,$this->aData))? LCI::Appended : LCI::Unread);
   return ($this->aItemList[$mKey] instanceof LCI);
}
```

LCI is another class unrelated to the tree shown above. `sItemClass` is a proper sub-class of LCI. So what is happening?

`createEntry` is supposed to return `false`, if `$this->aItemList` already has an entry for the same key, which is of type LCI. Otherwise it will create such an entry. Considering the first line shown, `getEntry` will only be called, if such an entry has been created and is of proper type. The conditional therein however does not find the entry and can create the entry anew, which of course does not result in a second entry in the array.

The key value used in the tests is `16` produced through a `floatval`.

Any ideas what is going on there?

Comment: This may just be an aside.. but you should never compare floats.  There is no guarantee that floatval('16') == floatval('16');  This is a standard programming practice, and PHP is no different.

Comment: Just to simplify understanding your code (and also to drive down some repetition), why not subsume the `isEntry()` functionality into a proper method?

Comment: In reference to my earlier comment... here's what the PHP manual says about float comparison:  http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to John Green I changed the key of my database to a string and it works perfectly. In fact, I was hunting down another problem. MC is a model and is passed as a reference to a view. At the end of the day I had differing values of the LCI instances in MC->aItemList[16] for the model constructed originally and the reference held in the view. In fact the LCI was constructed without any data, which should not be possible given the CTOR. But this problem also disappeared.

Lessons learned:

- checking floats for equality in PHP seems to be more troublesome than it usually is (never seen before that `$a != $a`, anywhere!)
- the result of `array_key_exists()` may be incongruent with the index access `[]` when using floats
- using floats as array indices might have side-effects beyond simple mis-association and beyond imagination

Thanks for checking the code and excluding the impossible to reveal the truth, no matter how improbable it seemed.